# Problema no get utilizando API do google com Angular

Tags: google-maps, angular, http, typescript

Tenho uma aplicação em angular que deve buscar na API do Google a long e lat.

Criei esse método abaixo para configurar minha chamada `HTTP.GET()`:

```
ObterGeolocalizacao(): Observable<any> {
    const cep = this.formulariServices.ObterFormulario().dadosPessoais.cep;

    return this.http.get(`${API_GOOGLE}cep${KEY_GOOGLE}`).map(response => response.json());
}
```

No meu *component* que vai realizar esse método, criei uma variável do tipo `any`, desta forma:

***googleGeo: any;***

No clique de um botão eu realizo a chamada do método desta forma:

```
try 
{
    this.googleGeoService.ObterGeolocalizacao().subscribe(res => this.googleGeo = res);

    console.log(this.googleGeo);
} 
catch (error) 
{
    console.log(error);
}
```

Ela não da erro. Porém, quando dou o `console.log(this.googleGeo);` para visualizar os dados recebidos, ele vem como `undefined`.

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Agradeço desde já...

Comment: O valor so existe dentro do subscribe pois e assíncrono.

Comment: Entendi! Testei aqui e realmente deu certo! Se quiser add uma resposta eu aprovo aqui! Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O valor so existe dentro do subscribe pois e assíncrono.

```
try 
{
    this.googleGeoService.ObterGeolocalizacao().subscribe(res => {
       this.googleGeo = res
       console.log(this.googleGeo); //existe aqui pois o http e assíncrono
});

    console.log(this.googleGeo); //aqui o http ainda não retornou.
} 
catch (error) 
{
    console.log(error);
}
```